# Simplify regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex pattern: `(1 Abc ([A-Z]+))|(Abc ([A-Z]+))|(1 ([A-Z]+))` that works as follows:

```
1 Abc TEST
Abc TEST
1 TEST
TEST
```

[Link of the demo](https://regex101.com/r/1TnC0Z/1)
It matches `TEST` in the first three cases, and does not match `TEST` in the last case.

The pattern looks a bit long, I want to make it shorter but keeping the same matching.
My tries ended with: `(1 |Abc )([A-Z]+)`, but this pattern does not match `TEST` in the first string ([link of the demo](https://regex101.com/r/6hEU57/1)).

Any suggestions how to simplify the first pattern and keep the same matching?

**EDIT:**
To avoid all confusions, all what I want to capture is `TEST` when it is preceded by '1 ', 'Abc ' or '1 Abc '.

Comment: You might be looking for [`^(?:\w+ +)+([A-Z]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/1TnC0Z/2) but it really depends on your actual input strings. As it stands, your question is not easily answerable.

Comment: You use multiple capturing groups. Each pair of parenthesis gets associated with a number. This is also true for the `([A-Z]+)` Part which is repeated multiple times. Depending on the prefix this will change the number of the capturing group. Thus you can not really change something and keep the exact same behaviour.

Comment: Do you really want to match `1` and/or `Abc` or any digit and/or any string? What about `2 DEF TEST`?

Comment: This is pretty short: `(?<= )\S+$`. It matches TEST in the first three cases, and does not match TEST in the last case.

Comment: @Toto, all what I want to capture is `TEST`, but only when it is in the first 3 cases (ie, when it is preceded by 'Abc ', '1 ' or '1 Abc '.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/1TnC0Z/3) what you want?

Comment: @Toto, yes that works too, thanks!

Comment: So it's ok to match "2 Foobar TEST"? That's not what your question says.

Comment: @Toto, to avoid matching 'Abc 1 TEST' just add `^` in the beginning of the pattern, and that should work perfectly!

Comment: @HeapOverflow, no, the uppercase sequence (which is `TEST` in this case, should be preceded by '1 ' or 'Abc ' or '1 Abc ').

Comment: @singrium Then why did you say that usr2564301's works?

Comment: @HeapOverflow, it works with the sequence of strings that I mentioned. I didn't test it with other strings. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

list = [
    '1 Abc TEST',
    'Abc TEST',
    '1 TEST',
    'TEST',
    '2 TEST',
    'XYZ TEST',
    'Abc 1 TEST',
]

for s in list:
    if re.match(r'^(?:1 Abc|1|Abc) ([A-Z]+)$', s):
        print('OK ' + s)
```

^**Output:**

```
OK 1 Abc TEST
OK Abc TEST
OK 1 TEST
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/1TnC0Z/5)

Answer (score 1):

You were very close. Your first group happens twice in the first test case. that's why it was not matching properly. You simply need to add a `+` ( or a `{1,2}` if you absolutly want one or two time this group.) after the OR group.

```
^(1 |Abc ){1,2}([A-Z]+)$
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/6hEU57/4)

I've also added beginning and end of string character for more accurate results.

Depending on your criteria, you could also change the `(1 |Abc )` for something a little bit more generic.

```
^((\d{1}|\w{3}) ){1,2}([A-Z]+)$
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/6hEU57/5)